# How to get Timestamp in xmpp incoming messages using smack library in android

Tags: java, android, timestamp, xmpp, smack

I am using Smack library to communicate with xmpp server. I am able to send/receive messages, but I want to get timestamp of incoming message.

Could you tell me please, is it possible at all? Because I can't find anything about this question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As per my knowledge about it, Timestamp is not part of the regular messages...

Comment: Yes, not the part of message same way as any kind of message id. This means there is no way to compare the messages and figure out which ones are shown to the user and which ones are not. This becomes important on reconnect and rejoin to the room.

Comment: have you solved this ??